# Insert into violation of PRIMARY or UNIQUE KEY constraint Firebird 2.5

Tags: sql, insert, key, unique, firebird

I am trying to insert a few values in an existing table, but first it makes nothing and 2nd time it shows me this error message.

[image]

My Unique KEY consists of a FK of a higher table and a counter.

If I check my tables there is no entry but it does not accept my UNIQUE Key.

Anybody with some ideas?

My test SQL Code for inserting into the view (same result with table)

```
INSERT INTO V_BRESZ(BRES_ID_LINKKEY, Maskenkey)
VALUES(29, 60);
```

For example my error message is:

> violation of PRIMARY or UNIQUE KEY constraint "UK_BRESZ" on table
>   "BRESZ". Problematic key value is ("MASKENKEY" = '        60',
>   "BRES_ID_LINKKEY" = 29).

But there is no such entry in my table / view.

Comment: What is your error message? What is your database schema? What are the values you're trying to insert? Please edit your question and put the data, schema and error message into your question.

Comment: Perhaps the data you are inserting has duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I edited my question. @GordonLinoff: This can't be true, because there are no such entries in my tables. Not even NULL rows.

Comment: Are you sure that you do not already have a record in V_BRESZ (and/or BRESZ table if it is different one) table with the values: MASKENKEY=60 and BRES_ID=29?

Comment: No doubt there is no such entries as I said before. Neither in my table nor in the view. If I insert new entries with AvERP (ERP GUI) the entries are inserted and I can see them in my table / view. But when I try to insert them with IBEXPERT (Firebird) - there are no entries but then I can't insert the same data with my ERP GUI with a error message that it is not unique.
So I don't know if the entries are stored somewhere else.

Comment: I find it rather curious the error messages suggest that `maskenkey` is actually a string value with leftpadded spaces. What is the DDL of the table and indexes? What does `select * from BRESZ where BRES_ID_LINKKEY+0 = 29` return? Have you tried using `ALTER INDEX <indexname> ACTIVE` on the unique index (or the index backing the unique constraint)?

Comment: Also, what is the full version of Firebird you're using?

Comment: DDL for my view: https://pastebin.com/B0Lsypg6
DDL for my tale: https://pastebin.com/sNgf42pv

select * from BRESZ where BRES_ID_LINKKEY+0 = 29 returns me the records like the screenshot above but ofc only where BRES_ID_LINKKEY is 29.
I will try Alter Index now.

Comment: Please add the information to your question (inline as a code block, not as a link). Questions need to be self-contained.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I tried to format as a code but it did not work, maybe it is too much code? THanks for help!

Comment: Then at least post the relevant parts of the table DDL (the table itself and the constraint definition). Don't forget to post your full Firebird version as well.

Comment: Making blind shoot here: we have a yet another convert from ISAM world :-) So he probably did not noticed such a thing as TRANSACTIONS, the core concept for SQL. Thus I suspect he does read his table into that grid in Transaction A, and then he inserts his records in Transaction B. Since he does not COMMIT the Transaction B - their changes are never seen by Transaction A which populates the grid. That would explain both effect - for the Transaction A world neither of same rows was inserted yet; for Transaction B one row was inserted and another same row is incoming.

Comment: @Arioch'The That's it! I had to commit all transactions manually in my stored procedure. Now all my records are displayed. But my problem for now is that I want to commit these transactions after executing my stored procedure. I've read that I can not use the commit; instruction in a stored procedure. But I need this to have a updated DB. Thanks for now guys!

Comment: `I had to commit all transactions manually in my stored procedure` - what? you can not commit transactions within PSQL block like Stored Procedure - because the procedure itself is being called and executed WITHIN some transaction started outside of it. You start a transaction, explicitly or implicitly by mere fact of executing any SQL statement (like `execute procedure YouNameIt(...)` ), then you run the procedure (and possible other related SQL statement too), then you commit it. That is the sequence.

Comment: Transaction is a mean to fuse several SQL commands into one atomic block. It is managed OUTSIDE those commands. An entity which issues the SQL command to execute the SP is the entity which can and is responsible to set up TX before and commit it after. Some uber-smart library might hide from you initiating of transactions by providing you with some "default" parameters and "default" TX object, still from Firebird's point of view that is how it goes.

Comment: Sorry, I did not express myself well. After calling my stored procedure I had to click on "commit transactions" manually. Before, the inserts / updates were not confirmed. I got it working finally. I had to execute the stored procedure external. I guess the .execute instruction in my code commited the changes aswell. Now it works. Thanks again lads!